# GitHub thinks I am first account despite using key from second account

Tags: git, macos, github, ssh

I have set up my `~/.ssh/config` file to allow me to connect to GitHub using ssh on two different accounts:

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host alt
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  HostName github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

I use the `~/.ssh/id_rsa` key for my first GitHub account (`id_rsa.pub` pasted in GitHub settings there).

I generated today a new key for my discord alt, and pasted `id_ed25519.pub` into my alt's GitHub settings.

Now when I do `ssh git@github.com` I get (as expected)

```
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Hi original_account! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
Connection to github.com closed.
```

But I seem to be unable to authenticate with the new account, look at this

Now when I do `ssh git@github.com` I get (as expected)

```
$ ssh git@alt
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Hi original_account! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
Connection to github.com closed.
```

Why does it still think I am `original_account`? Even

```
$ ssh -o "IdentitiesOnly=yes" -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 git@alt
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Hi original_account! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
Connection to github.com closed.
```

How can I force git to recognise the distinction between the two private keys I wish to use, so that I can use these two accounts via ssh from the same laptop?

---

```
ssh -vvv -o "IdentitiesOnly=yes" -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 git@alt
```

shows some lines

```
debug1: Connecting to github.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
...
debug1: Will attempt key: ~/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:avZRhZ1AbwN1ECfb1A/93OG8dm0ewx33pD6asJs/I2Y explicit agent
debug1: Will attempt key: ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:XWhJ7Gkt13Rh3Whqwf9yH/K4lL15HaoX1+cYvbxgfpY explicit agent
debug1: Will attempt key: ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:XWhJ7Gkt13Rh3Whqwf9yH/K4lL15HaoX1+cYvbxgfpY explicit
```

Comment: Check the output of `ssh -vvv` to see which key is actually used.

Comment: @iBug I edited the question with the lines I think are relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The problem

From [`ssh_config` (5)](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config):

> For each parameter, the first obtained value will be used.

And

> It is possible to have multiple identity files specified in configuration files; all these identities will be tried in sequence. Multiple **IdentityFile** directives will add to the list of identities tried.

So this is what happened:

- `ssh` reads the config, applies `Host *` config, and adds `id_rsa` to the key list.
- `ssh` sees the `Host alt` section and applies `Host github.com`, and adds `id_ed25519` to the key list. (`AddKeysToAgent` from this section is discarded, though it doesn't make a difference)
- `ssh` connects to `git@github.com` and started trying keys one-by-one. Since `id_rsa` appears earlier in the config, it is tried first.
- GitHub reports a successful authentication for `id_rsa` and an SSH session is established. Any further keys are discarded.

#### Why doesn't `IdentitiesOnly` work?

> Specifies that ssh(1) should only use the configured authentication identity and certificate files (either the default files, or those explicitly configured in the ssh_config files or passed on the ssh(1) command-line).

As said, `IdentitiesOnly` tells SSH to ignore keys from the SSH agent, but doesn't restrict the "key search list" to the current config section. (In fact, there's no way to do this.) This means `id_rsa` will be attempted unless you remove the directive from your SSH config file.

### The solution

The solution is to put `Host *` section at the bottom of your `.ssh/config` file, so any host-specific overrides can take priority. This is also guided by the man page:

> Since the first obtained value for each parameter is used, more host-specific declarations should be given near the beginning of the file, and general defaults at the end.

Additionally, you need not have `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa` in your `Host *` section, as this path is among [a default list](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#IdentityFile) that SSH will look for keys in absence of explicit specifications.

Comment: Do you know why `IdentitiesOnly yes` in `Host alt` didn't work ?

Comment: I moved the `Host *` section to the bottom, but the behaviour is still identical. Do I need to refresh ssh somehow?

Comment: @minseong Well in that case, try removing `IdentityFile` from `Host *` section - you probably don't need it - so as to remove possible interference. I'm not sure about how SSH decides in which order it tries keys.

Comment: That works, but will it still use my `id_rsa` key for all other hosts?

Comment: @minseong `~/.ssh/id_rsa` is among several [default keys](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#IdentityFile) that SSH will attempt even if (and particularly when) no keys are specified, so that's not a thing to worry about.